# Rotating 3D points across a horizontal arbitrary axis

Tags: c#, c++, 3d, game-engine, trigonometry

I have a 3D engine I am developing with software rendering of all graphics, mainly for the purpose of understanding deeper how things work.

Right now I have everything I need (map-based coordinate system, 3D coordinate system, multi-threaded texturing engine, multi-camera perspective functionality, block-level collision/hit detection, projectile and simple particle engine), crappy physics, etc.)

I built everything and left rotational math to the minimum because I've been TRYING to learn trig at the same time (I know what you're going to say, but keep it to yourself, i'm a great programmer, not a mathematician; lol)....

However... I just can't get it right and after days it's driving me nuts. I've been researching and reading and coding and I just can't figure it out.

[image]

This is my current rotational function, it spins the nodes clockwise on the Y axis.

```
Public Function RotatePoints(nodeCollection() As Point3d, centerPoint As Point, angleInDegrees As Double) As Point3d()
    For l = 0 To nodeCollection.Count - 1
        Dim angleInRadians As Double = angleInDegrees * (Math.PI / 180)
        Dim cosTheta As Double = Math.Cos(angleInRadians)
        Dim sinTheta As Double = Math.Sin(angleInRadians)

        Dim pointToRotate As New Point
        pointToRotate.X = nodeCollection(l).X
        pointToRotate.Y = nodeCollection(l).Y

        Dim key As New Point
        key.X = CInt(cosTheta * (pointToRotate.X - centerPoint.X) - sinTheta * (pointToRotate.Y - centerPoint.Y) + centerPoint.X)
        key.Y = CInt(sinTheta * (pointToRotate.X - centerPoint.X) + cosTheta * (pointToRotate.Y - centerPoint.Y) + centerPoint.Y)

        With nodeCollection(l)
            .X = key.X
            .Y = key.Y
        End With
    Next

    Return nodeCollection
End Function
```

My goal is to have the object rotate around the view perspective axis horizontally. Similar to how you can look around in a game and the world moves around you from side to side.

[image]

I don't care what programming language responses are in, I am fluent in many, but I suck at trig :(

I have been trying to do this with no help, but i'm stuck and the computations for roll, pitch and yaw are not typically offered in programming syntax and are stifling to understand, which is the whole reason i'm doing this --- to learn.

Comment: Have you used matrix? With rotation matrix you can do amazing things pretty "easily". Tell me while I look for an old 3D project.

Comment: I have not, i've read about it but the implementations i've seen were not well done. I'm interested in hearing more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a full 3D rotation, you will have to look at **rotation matrix**.

If you are working on 3D engine, you have to learn how to use it. It can be a bit impressive at first, but it's not so difficult.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix

With matrix you can manipulate objects in all the way possibles:
Scale
Rotation
Translation

You first need to learn how to multiply Matrix (usually 4x4, you can search why you will find answers) with other matrix and with vector.

That way for each object of your world, you will store the position of earch vertex (an absolute position, based on the object origin), then you will store a transformation matrix (scale, rotation and translation (= position) of the object in the world). Finally, you will have a camera matrix, which will make you able to move the world in the oposite direction and position of the camera, to make it seems like the camera is moving.

So:

Lets say our object is just a point.

Object:

• Vertex `[1, 2, -1, 1]` (x, y, z, and w usually equal to 1)

• Scale matrix (let's say scaled x2.0 on y)

```
[1, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 2, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1]
```

• The rotation matrix (let's say 90° on z, we look at the wiki and let's go)

```
c = cos(90°) and s = sin(90°)

[ c, s, 0, 0]   [ 0, 1, 0, 0]
[-s, c, 0, 0]   [-1, 0, 0, 0]
[ 0, 0, 1, 0] = [ 0, 0, 1, 0]
[ 0, 0, 0, 1]   [ 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

• The translation matrix (let's say -2, 1, 4)

```
 [1, 0, 0, -2]
 [0, 1, 0,  1]
 [0, 0, 1,  4]
 [0, 0, 0,  1]
```

Now we only need to combine all of it and we got a new point:

`T * R * S`

```
[1, 0, 0, -2]   [ 0, 1, 0, 0]   [1, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 0,  1]   [-1, 0, 0, 0]   [0, 2, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1,  4] * [ 0, 0, 1, 0] * [0, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 0,  1]   [ 0, 0, 0, 1]   [0, 0, 0, 1]

=

[ 0, 1, 0,-2]   [1, 0, 0, 0]   [ 0, 2, 0,-2]
[-1, 0, 0, 1]   [0, 2, 0, 0]   [-1, 0, 0, 1]
[ 0, 0, 1, 4] * [0, 0, 1, 0] = [ 0, 0, 1, 4]
[ 0, 0, 0, 1]   [0, 0, 0, 1]   [ 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

This is our object matrix.

Now we just have to multiply our vertex by it to have it's position in the world:

```
[ 0, 2, 0,-2]   [ 1]   [2]
[-1, 0, 0, 1]   [ 2]   [0]
[ 0, 0, 1, 4] * [-1] = [3]
[ 0, 0, 0, 1]   [ 1]   [1]
```

Which gives a point at (2, 0, 3, 1).

---

Now we will calculate the camera matrix, to apply it's transformation on the world.

You need vector calculation (like cross product or dot product)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Euclidean_norm

Your camera is 2 points, a first which is it's position, and another one which is the "look at" point.

With that you can calculate those values:

```
zaxis = normal(At - Eye)
xaxis = normal(cross(Up, zaxis))
yaxis = cross(zaxis, xaxis)

[ xaxis.x        ,  yaxis.x        ,  zaxis.x        , 0]
[ xaxis.y        ,  yaxis.y        ,  zaxis.y        , 0]
[ xaxis.z        ,  yaxis.z        ,  zaxis.z        , 0]
[-dot(xaxis, eye), -dot(yaxis, eye), -dot(zaxis, eye), 1]
```

Here you have your camera matrix, you only need to apply it on each vertex of your world and you're done.

I don't remember if that formula applies perspective.

If you are doing everything by yourself, you will also need to deal with clipping (when a point is behing the camera, the math are broken when dealing with perspective).

Also to remember in which order you need to multiply the matrices, look at that:

```
Cam * Translation * Rotation * Scale * Point
```

The point is always last (matrices math, sry), and the closest matrix to it is the first applied to it, so here we first apply Scale on the point, then Rotation, then Translation, and finally the Camera positioning.

Good luck.

Comment: Interesting. So this takes my 3D world out of two coordinate systems (the virtual, and the physical map) and brings it into a 3rd or even, technically 4th coordinate system which holds a matrix of absolutes and a matrix of calculated relative vertexes, am I correct?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure of what you mean, but I think I get it. The "virtual" and "physical" coordinate system would more be like  the "object" and "world" coordinate system. You can even create nested object group, like if you had a world, and once calculated, considering it as a single object.

Comment: I have a lot of work ahead of me, do you have any code samples you could recommend?

Comment: I have old code, but it's very ugly, it was in C, I was a begginner and I had some restrictions making the code even uglier. And it was my first time I worked with 3D, if you really really want I can show you that, but you are warned. (and it's not fully finished)

Comment: Tonight I discovered in MSDN a full library for matrix rotation, but no source examples :(

Comment: Anything you can show me would be great, I only want to learn and understand the how's and the why's of this whole concept

Comment: https://github.com/Antonito/Tekdoom It is C code (not the best language for this AT ALL, and it was a school project with short deadline and a norm (not more than 25 lines by function, not more than 5 function by file, etc..)). You can find the 3D code in src/engine/.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot I had an XNA game programming book sitting on my shelf that deals with all of this as well, so I am combing through.